# Indexed graph feature request for Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am working on http://tradingderivatives.nl/DAX-root.html . Obvious problem: sliding is slow. Reason behind this is that the indexing to 100 on the left side of the selection has to be done by explicit coding in Javascript - at least, I did not find a better way to do this. The Google Vizualisation libary is also slow - much slower than the Dygraphs annotated timeline.

I found the range-selector example in the dygraphs online gallery. This is almost what I need - apart from the automated indexing to 100 on the left of the graph.

Questions/feature requests:

- Is there a way to have the graph automatically indexed to 100? This indexing would make Dygraphs suddenly ideal for comparing trends of different data sets over any time range! Cool. I need this re-indexing even after zooming in to selected data of the full data range.
- Can the area below a section of the graph be coloured as is currently done in http://tradingderivatives.nl/DAX-root.html? In this way I don't have to work with three data series. This trick is clear from the code of the DAX page. Highlighting a section of the graph is supported in Dygraphs, colouring below a graph is supported, but conditional highlighting per data segment appears to be unsupported - and this is the easiest way to work with automatic indexing to 100.

Answer (score 1):

See the straw broom example for how to have the graph automatically indexed to 100 by using the rebase plugin:
https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/tests/straw-broom.html

```
<script src="../dist/dygraph.js"></script>
<script src="../src/extras/rebase.js"></script>
<script>
    ...
    var rebase = new Dygraph.Plugins.Rebase(100);
    new Dygraph(chartDiv, stockData, { plugins: [rebase] });
</script>
```